# How do I deserialise different NodaTime LocalDate patterns within the same JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net, nodatime

I'm trying to use NodaTime to interpret dates retrieved from a third-party API. The dates come in an annoying array of formats in the same response, one that I'm particularly having trouble with is similar to:

```
{
    "ShortDate": "2017-01-01",
    "LongDate": "01 January 2017"
}
```

I can correctly deserialise one format or the other using NodaPatternConverter, but not both.

A simple example showing the problem is like this:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet;
using NodaTime.Text;

namespace NodaLocalDateConverterTest
{
    class ExampleDatedModel
    {
        public LocalDate ShortDate { get; set; }

        public LocalDate LongDate { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var exampleJsonString =
@"{
    ""ShortDate"": ""2017-01-01"",
    ""LongDate"": ""01 January 2017""
}";

            var serialisationSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            //NodaTime default converter supports ShortDate format
            serialisationSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);

            //Exception on LongDate property
            var deserialisedExample1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleDatedModel>(exampleJsonString, serialisationSettings);

            serialisationSettings.Converters.Remove(NodaConverters.LocalDateConverter);
            serialisationSettings.Converters.Add(new NodaPatternConverter<LocalDate>(LocalDatePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("dd MMMM yyyy")));

            //Exception on ShortDate property
            var deserialisedExample2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExampleDatedModel>(exampleJsonString, serialisationSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the default serialiser gives throws an exception on the LongDate property:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: The value string does not match the required
>   number from the format string "yyyy". Value being parsed: '^01 January
>   2017'. (^ indicates error position.)

Replacing with a custom pattern converter throws an exception on the ShortDate property:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'NodaTime.Text.UnparsableValueException' occurred in
>   Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: The value string does not match a simple
>   character in the format string " ". Value being parsed: '20^17-01-01'.
>   (^ indicates error position.)

In principle I think I could use two different converters for the two properties, such as

```
class ExampleDatedModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ShortDateConverter)]
    public LocalDate ShortDate { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(LongDateConverter)]
    public LocalDate LongDate { get; set; }
}
```

However I don't see how to use NodaTime's NodaPatternConverter with the attribute as you can't instantiate the converter with a pattern.

The [documentation](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/userguide/serialization) helpfully says "Custom converters can be created easily from patterns using NodaPatternConverter." but doesn't give any examples!

Possible solutions I've though about are

- Create a pair of converters derived from NodaPatternConverter which are configured for the two patterns.

  - NodaPatternConverter is sealed, so can't be inherited from.
- Create a pair of converters derived from JsonConverter to deal with both patterns

  - I guess these would call two versions of LocalDatePattern.Parse with the different patterns internally.
  - Reimplementation of the whole of JsonConverter seems overkill.
- Deserialise the dates as strings then convert the dates afterwards.

  - Needs implementing for each class which has a mixture of types.
  - Makes generic methods fetching resources from the API more complex.

But I hope I'm just missing a way of marking up the resource classes to use existing converters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does indeed seem to be a use case we hadn't considered. For "normal" usage, sealing `NodaPatternConverter` feels like the right approach - but when a `JsonConverter` has to be specified by *type* rather than instantiated, the sealing is frustrating. I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/issues/656) to fix this in 2.0, which I'm hoping to release in the next month or so. (It's [now implemented](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime/pull/657) - the pull request shows sample usage as well.)

However, for the meantime I probably *would* just fork `NodaPatternConverter` - and add a comment saying that it's only there until you can use 2.0.

You may want to trim it down a bit, as you probably don't need the extra validation, assuming you control all the code that's going to serialize data - if you don't need to worry about non-ISO `LocalDate` values, you probably don't need validation.

The other aspect is that if you're only ever *parsing* using the converters, you don't need the writing side at all - you could just throw an exception for that at the moment, potentially.

An alternative to unsealing `NodaPatternConverter` is to have a simple (abstract) `DelegatingConverterBase` type, which delegates to another `JsonConverter`. Typical usage would be something like:

```
public sealed class ShortDateConverter : DelegatingConverterBase
{
    public ShortDateConverter() : base(NodaConverters.LocalDate) {}
}
```

That might be a more elegant separation of concerns - and implementable with less code until it's part of Noda Time, too:

```
public abstract class DelegatingConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly JsonConverter original;

    protected DelegatingConverterBase(JsonConverter original)
    {
        this.original = original;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        original.WriteJson(writer, value, serializer);

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        original.ReadJson(reader, objectType, existingValue, serializer);

    public override bool CanRead => original.CanRead;

    public override bool CanWrite => original.CanWrite;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => original.CanConvert(objectType);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting some thought into that. I probably would have come up with something equivalent, but less elegant!

Comment: @Xcodo: I'm glad I didn't have to unseal `NodaPatternConverter` in the end. I definitely prefer this in terms of separation of concerns. I wonder why there isn't something like this in Json.NET itself...